Can there be a continuous 3D space whose "local geodesic cross-section" is other than the sphere?
In $\mathbb{R}^3$ for example, given a point $p$, we can take the family of lines that pass through $p$, and say that the cross-section of this set of lines has the topology of a sphere.  For example, if we suppose the standard Euclidean metric, then this cross-section is the boundary of a ball centered at $p$.
Is it possible to create a continuous 3D space where this cross-section forms a different closed surface, such as a Klein bottle, projective plane, etc.?  One question would be whether this can be done at every point in the space, i.e. every such cross-section about every point is of the same type, e.g. all cross-sections are Klein bottles.  Another version would be to ask if this could be done only about one point or a discrete set of points, i.e. all cross-sections emanating from $p$ are Klein bottles, but cross-sections from any other point are still spheres.  If it is possible, then what would be the properties of such a space?
Note: I'm not sure if we have to invoke a metric in order to talk about this properly?  I was kind of trying to avoid it because for example if the metric is Lorentzian, then the geodesic cross-section is not even closed in the first place, being a hyperboloid, so I guess we'd have to explicitly restrict ourselves to positive-definite metrics.

Already the first paragraph is wrong. I do not understand the rest. How much topology do you know?

@MoisheKohan  Oh ok I probably misused the terminology, but let's just say that, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the set of all points $q$ a distance $\epsilon$ from $p$ is a sphere.  But could there be a space where the set of all points $q$ a distance $\epsilon$ from $p$ forms e.g. a Klein bottle instead?

OK, this is better but still unclear since quantifiers are missing. Do you mean: is there a metric space $X$ such that  For every $p\in X$ and every $\epsilon>0$ the metric sphere $S(p, \epsilon)$ is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle? That would be an interesting and nontrivial question.

@MoisheKohan  Yes that’s exactly what I mean, thanks for clarifying!

If the homeomorphism to Klein bottle depends continuously on $\epsilon$, one can prove that such space does not exist. Without this extra assumption, I am not sure.
